# Override View.onDraw() method, but sometimes the customer view keep blank until touch it.

Tags: android, ondraw

I override View.onDraw() method and draw some lines on it, but sometimes it shows nothing until touch it.

Comment: Paste your code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

A View's onDraw() is called when:

-> The view is initially drawn

-> Whenever [invalidate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29) is called on the view

Check if you need to call invalidate(). or please give the full code with xml